# How to add new columns to Flat File conn in SSIS without resetting data types for existing cols

Tags: ssis, ssis-2005

SSIS 2005

I have a flat file connection which is the result of a db dump.

New columns have been added to the file and now they need to be added to the connection manager.

There are a lot of columns and not all of them have the default dataypes

How can I make it see the additional columns without doing a full refresh, thereby causing all the datatypes to reset?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open the flat file connection manager and go to the `Advanced` tab.

If the new columns are appended to the end of the flat file, click `New`.  Otherwise highlight the existing column name positioned before the new column, click the `double down arrow next to the New button`, and select `Insert After`.

Once the new column is added, you can select it and modify the properties of the column (IE Name, Datatype, Length).